# SQL error: having operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write a sql script, that has to show all man client, whose maximum income twice bigger, than minimum income overall.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  customer_rk,
  max(monthly_income_amt),
  min(monthly_income_amt),
  max(monthly_income_amt) / min(monthly_income_amt) AS income_ratio
FROM asql.individual_customer
WHERE middle_nm LIKE '%ВИЧ'
GROUP BY customer_rk
HAVING income_ratio > 2;
```

`middle_nm like '%ВИЧ'` - it is for sorting men by their middle name (Russian language requirments)

Here is how table looks like:

[image]

A receives such error:

> ERROR: column "income_ratio" does not exist (line 6)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why SELECT DISTINCT? The GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `income_ratio` write in having clause as `max(monthly_income_amt) / min(monthly_income_amt)>2` .

Also `distinct` does not make sense as you are grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Need modification in your having clause as below.

```
SELECT
      DISTINCT
      customer_rk,
      max(monthly_income_amt),
      min(monthly_income_amt),
      max(monthly_income_amt) / min(monthly_income_amt) AS income_ratio
    FROM asql.individual_customer
    WHERE middle_nm LIKE '%ВИЧ'
    GROUP BY customer_rk
    HAVING (max(monthly_income_amt) / min(monthly_income_amt)) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query up in a derived table. Then you can put income_ratio in the WHERE clause:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT
      customer_rk,
      max(monthly_income_amt),
      min(monthly_income_amt),
      max(monthly_income_amt) / min(monthly_income_amt) AS income_ratio
    FROM asql.individual_customer
    WHERE middle_nm LIKE '%ВИЧ'
    GROUP BY customer_rk
) dt
where income__ratio > 2;
```